# Get and set ACLs using powershell on a mounted disk

Tags: powershell

I have a SAN volume mounted to a directory on a Windows 2008R2 server and I'd like to get and set the ACLs on that disk device using powershell.  If I do the following I get the permissions of the directory the disk is mounted to instead of the permissions on the drive:

```
Get-Acl C:\shares\PS-TEST
```

I've tried the following but with no such luck:

```
Get-Acl \\?\PhysicalDrive19
```

What do I have to do to {Get,Set}-ACL on the disk device instead of the mount point folder?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following for getting an ACL object.

```
$aclObject = [io.directory]::GetAccessControl("\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0")
```

Use the following for setting an ACL object.

```
[io.directory]::SetAccessControl("\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0",$aclObject)
```